# Problema al construir APK

Tags: android, android-studio

Acabe de hacer una aplicación e intente generar el correspondiente apk pero me da este error. Alguien me podría ayudar a corregir este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este en mi archivo gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kevtho.applicacion"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile('com.android.support:design:23.4.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

y este es el manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/movitaxi_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyABeOQ2-PL0Zx6GpjsX6VkFwMj4AZ-8e-c" />

</application>
```

Comment: Kevtho, ve mi respuesta, si tienes dentro de /libs el archivo android-support-v4.jar eliminalo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo pero al hacerlo me salen otros errores

Comment: por lo que veo excluyes todos los support-v4

Answer (score 1):

Este error se genera por clases duplicadas, es diferente cada caso, en el error marca la clase `LogWriter` que se contiene dentro de la "support library V4".

Veo que usas la librería de soporte pero también cargas dependencias de `/libs`,

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

verifica que no tengas dentro de `/libs` el archivo `android-support-v4.jar`.